# How to configure 'mainClassName' for Spring Boot Application in a Kotlin Gradle multi-module project?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

I have a [Gradle multi-module project in Kotlin](https://github.com/Partyschaum/kotlin-spring-boot-multi-project) using Spring Boot in some of the modules.

I use the `'org.springframework.boot'` and `'io.spring.dependency-management'` plugin in the project's root `build.gradle` which besides other things provide the `bootRun` task.

AFAIK I need to configure the `mainClassName` (or entry point) like this:

```
springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'de.shinythings.hexagon.HexagonApplicationKt'
}
```

While this works in the subproject that contains the actual Spring Boot application it does not work in the root project.

I want to be able to configure it in the root project because I want to be able to run my project with `./gradlew bootRun` instead of `./gradlew configuration:bootRun`.

Other tasks like `./gradlew build` or `./gradlew test` work fine.

Here is the root project's `build.gradle` ([link](https://github.com/Partyschaum/kotlin-spring-boot-multi-project/blob/master/build.gradle)):

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.10'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':configuration')
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'de.shinythings.hexagon.HexagonApplicationKt'
}

subprojects {
    group = 'de.shinythings.hexagon'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    ext {
        mockKVersion = '1.10.2'
    }

    apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.4.RELEASE')
        }
    }

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
            allWarningsAsErrors = true
        }
    }

    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
            allWarningsAsErrors = true
        }
    }
}
```

In the subproject/module this setting works ([link](https://github.com/Partyschaum/kotlin-spring-boot-multi-project/blob/master/configuration/build.gradle)) :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.4.10'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    implementation project(':application')
    implementation project(':adapters:persistence')
    implementation project(':adapters:web')

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'

    implementation('com.h2database:h2')
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'de.shinythings.hexagon.HexagonApplicationKt'
}
```

What do I have to do to configure the `mainClassName` is the root's project `build.gradle`?